# jQuery remove twice function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please consider this very simplified sample.

Below code remove a fixed nav bar from pages when screen size is small. It is named `removeFixedNavbar()`.

This should be done when **document is loaded** and when **window is resized**. Please see the code. Well, this code seems some how ugly (calling `removeFixedNavbar()` twice, is it a better way to write it (with less code).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    removeFixedNav();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        removeFixedNav();
    });    
});
```

Comment: This would probably be better with CSS and media queries.

Comment: This is a sample and the `removeFixedNav` function can not be done with css

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi  add class and remove class can help you to achieve you solution..!! and CSS./...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(removeFixedNav);
$(window).resize(removeFixedNav);
```

This should work, but i think it should be doable using `CSS Media Queries` only (depends upon the use-case).

**Even simpler could be:**

```
$(function(){
  $(window).resize(removeFixedNav).trigger("resize");
});
```

Placing it at bottom most part can get rid of `$(function(){...})`

**An other equivalent version can be:**

```
$(function(){
      $(window).trigger("resize");
});
$(window).resize(removeFixedNav);
```

Comment: it is bad practise to call one event inside another, there can be another handlers on `resize` event

Comment: @GeneR I don't that will be an issue here, can you quote an example.

Comment: why should be called all `resize` event handlers if window wasn't really resized?

Answer (score 1):

Well you call it twice in document.ready.
Place window. resize outside document.ready event.